# How i can get requestcode from pending intent for showing which message delivered

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

I have pending intent to show message status after send

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

This is my pending intent

```
deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
```

When sms is delivered, I want to get `requestcode` from `PendingIntent` to show which sms is delivered, but in `onReceive()` method I can't get `requestcode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your SMS `id` to the `PendingIntent` like this:

```
Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED);
deliveryIntent.putExtra("id", id);
deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, deliveryIntent, 0);
```

Then, in `onReceive()` you can get the SMS id like this:

```
int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
if (id >= 0) {
    // Got a valid id...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i used your code but when i getting requestecode always is 0

Comment: Check what id you put into the Intent. Add some logging. Debug it step by step.

Comment: Tanks,this code is perfect,i could  get msg id, but when i sending  several msg only latest id save into intent and all msg have a id...

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense either. You should have a different `PendingIntent` for each message since the `id` should be unique. However, if that isn't working, you can guarantee a different `PendingIntent` for each message by creating the `Intent` with a unique ACTION. Do it like this: `Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED + id);` (assuming that `DELIVERED` is a `String`).